# Compilation error with Symfony Webpack Encore and FontAwesome

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony-3.4, font-awesome-5, webpack-encore

I'm currently writing a Symfony 3.4 app with Bootstrap and FontAwesome Pro.  I have the following custom .scss file:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "burnt-orange": #fa7334,
    "light-blue": #67e2f5,
    "dark-blue": #006f80,
    "beige": #f5d5bc
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro";
```

My `/project_root/app/Resources/js/app.js`:

```
import '../scss/custom.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
window.Popper = require('popper.js');

require('bootstrap');
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableVersioning()
    .addEntry('app', './app/Resources/assets/js/app.js')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And the relevant script from my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "encore dev --watch"
  }
```

When I try running `$ npm run dev`, I get the following error:

> webpack is watching the files…
>
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   10:01:31 PM
>
> error  in ./app/Resources/assets/scss/custom.scss
>
> Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
>   ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> (function () { ^
>         Invalid CSS after " */": expected selector, was "(function () {"
>         in /home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/fontawesome.js
>   (line 5, column 1)
>       at runLoaders (/home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:286:20)
>       at /home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at /home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (/home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at Object.render [as callback] (/home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:52:13)
>       at Object.done [as callback] (/home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8077:18)
>       at options.error (/home/kevin/www/diva/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)
>
> @ ./app/Resources/assets/js/app.js 1:0-29

Obviously, the error has to do with how I'm attempting to include FontAwesome, but I'm new to node, Bootstrap, and FontAwesome, so I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  Do I even need to import FontAwesome?  [Their docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) say to simply reference the module's `css/all.css`, but since the same documentation says to save the FontAwesome module as a development dependency, I'm not sure it will be available when I tell Webpack Encore to compile for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my `custom.scss` file to this (note the last line) fixed the issue:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "burnt-orange": #fa7334,
    "light-blue": #67e2f5,
    "dark-blue": #006f80,
    "beige": #f5d5bc
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css";
```